# c++ main() brain teaser

Tags: c++

Can you think of a situation where your program would crash without reaching the breakpoint which you set at the beginning of main()?

My answer is during the initialization of static variables, but not sure...

Comment: Quite a few things happen before `main()` gets called, not all of them in your code...

Comment: Does C++ have static{} blocks? Crashy magic might be possible if it does.

Comment: @Ignacio, care to mention a few such things?

Comment: Everything in crt1.o/crt.lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple example

```
struct abc
{
   abc()
   {
       int* p = 0;
       *p = 42; // Drat!
   }
};

abc obj;
int main(){}
```

Comment: @Nawaz : On most implementations yes. Technically its UB.

Comment: @Prasoon: But not guaranteed!

Comment: @Nawaz : Yes but I couldn't think of an implementation where this would work without crashing.

Comment: @Prasoon: If UB doesn't mean crash, then it might not crash and instead, might do some other harm (or not harm at all, if you're lucky). After all, its Undefined Behavior :P

Comment: @Nawaz - On the systems I know of, where a null pointer access isn't caught by the hardware, it will instead overwrite the interrupt vector. "Probably" crashes almost as fast. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: My question is : is this guaranteed?

Comment: @Nawaz - No it is not guaranteed. In the interrupt vector case (real mode?) there is of course one chance in 256 that a byte you overwrite actually had that value before. Then it looks like it was working.

Comment: @Bo Persson: All I'm saying is that it isn't guaranteed. If you disagree with me, then your comments directed at me would make *some* sense.

Comment: @Nawaz : Where in the question has the OP mentioned about guarantee clause? :P

Comment: @Prasoon: I'm not saying that either :P

Answer (score 3):

THe above examples are true, but in my experience it's usually due to some problem loading a DLL...

Answer (score 2):

My answer gives 100% guarantee that this will crash before `main()`.

```
#include <exception>

struct A
{
   A() 
   {
       std::terminate(); //from <exception>
       //you can also call std::abort() from <cstdlib>
   }
};
A a;

int main(){}
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/JIhcz

---

Another solution:

```
struct A
{
   A() 
   {
       throw "none";
   }
};
A a;

int main(){}
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/daaMe